# The set if affine?

Tags: affine-geometry

The Set $\{ Ax + b | Fx = g \}$, is it affine?
How can I prove it?

My answer is yes, the intuition is that $\{ x | Fx = g \}$ is a solution space of equation $Fx = g$, thus it is a linear subspace.

The $Ax + b$ is a linear transformation plus a translation. So the final result is a affine set.

Welcome to comment on my understanding.

Comment: $Fx=g$ has an _affine_ solution space. $Fx=0$ has a linear one. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
1.  A set is an affine subspace, iff it is the kernel of an affine transformation $T: x \mapsto Mx+c$
2.  An image of an affine subspace under an affine transformation is an affine subspace.

Comment: I don't understand the 1., what doest it mean "it is the kernel of an affine transformation"? I havenot met with "kernel" yet. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Well, $\ker T := \{x | Tx=0 \}$. You might know it as a "null-space"?

Comment: yes, I understand the concept of null-space, is "kernel" here same as null-space(solution space of $Tx = b $)?

Comment: @user2262504 Kernel is the solution space of $Tx = 0$. But an affine transformation with kernel $\{Ax = b\}$ is $Tx = Ax - b$.